# why looks this site different on Chrome ,Firefox compared wirth IE10

Tags: html

I noticed when I look to this site (http://www.20thingsilearned.com/nl-NL) I noticed that on IE the book is much bigger then when you look at the site with Chrome or Firefox.

Anyone a idea what is the cause of this and if this can be solved easily.

Roelof

Comment: Have you heard something about cross browser compatibility?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Your comment might sound a little cryptic.

Comment: @dystroy Actually am closing this as too localized :p

Comment: @Mr.Alien I agree with that. We shouldn't be asked to do the debugging of a whole site.

Comment: @dystroy Ya, these types of questions are just getting more and more day by day .. btw [tag:off-topic] chimp in your pic is good :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Internet Explorer 10 default zoom level. Probably it is set to 125%. If you set it to 100%, it should look like in the other browsers (You can change it with the gear icon -> zoom).